# What's a good strategy in R to store results in list form to access it later on by names rather than indices?

Tags: r

I would like to automate the results creation process when I apply certain modeling techniques. So I'll have different parameters which will be applied (e.g. hierarchical clustering distances and linkage methods). The results will have a matrix form so that I can access individual results by specifying the model parameters (eg. single, euclidean). In a dataframe I could name  the columns and rows and access the elements simply by `df[rname[1],cname[1]]`. As far I as I read its not possible to use data frame objects to store list results. So I need lists for storing list-results. But in lists I can only specify `lst$cname[1]` and not both dimensions. Am I correct?

```
# data frame layout for numeric results does not work with list results
rname<-c("u","v","w")
cname<-c("ave","single")

# dataframe for results but does not work for results which are lists
paste.1<-function(x,y) paste(x,y,sep=".")
df1<-data.frame(lapply(cname,paste.1,x=rname),row.names=rname)
colnames(df1)<-cname

# creating list for results - do not get a good idea to proceed from here Advices??
lst<-(lapply(cname,paste.1,x=rname))
names(lst)<-cname

# results example - could be anything else 
# with a dataframe I could use df1[rname,cname]<-foo(rname,cname)
# with lists I guess its not as easy
require(graphics)
ave.u <- hclust(dist(USArrests,"euclidean"), cname[1])
ave.v <- hclust(dist(USArrests,"maximum"), cname[1])
ave.w <- hclust(dist(USArrests,"manhattan"), cname[1])
single.u <- hclust(dist(USArrests,"euclidean"), cname[2])
single.v <- hclust(dist(USArrests,"maximum"), cname[2])
single.w <- hclust(dist(USArrests,"manhattan"), cname[2])
```

Well I am not sure if there is a solution which I guess must exist. At the end I just want to access the list results via the row names and column names. I know I could transfer row/column names to numerical ones and then play with assigning proper indexes to find my results in a list of length(`rname`) x length(`cname`) but since the data frame is so nicely to use I am assuming it must be an easy way to store it more user friendly. It might also be the case that I did not really get well into the concept of lists since I am just starting to play around with R. So my question is: What would be a good strategy to store the structured results (which are lists) using R?

Comment: Is it possible that you can actually make it into a data-frame?  As far as I understand, data-frame has to be rectangular, while the list can be of any dimensions.

Comment: AFAIK dataframes in r are implemented as lists of the same length.

Comment: I think this question is terribly confusing, especially the example. A clear description of what you are trying to accomplish would go a long way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One can have a matrix of lists:

```
nr <- length(rname)
nc <- length(cname)

m <- matrix(list(), nr, nc, dimnames = list(rname, cname))

m[["u", "ave"]] <- ave.u

# etc.
```

For example, form the row names, `rnm`, and column names, `cnm`, and a data frame, `g`, of all combinations of their values.  Then create a matrix of lists, `m` :

```
rnm <- c("euclidean", "maximum", "manhattan")
cnm <- c("ave", "single")
g <- expand.grid(rnm, cnm)
f <- function(i) hclust(dist(USArrests, g[i,1]), g[i,2])
m <- matrix(lapply(1:nrow(g), f), length(rnm), dimnames = list(rnm, cnm))
```

We can access elements like this:

```
> m[["euclidean", "single"]]

Call:
hclust(d = dist(USArrests, g[i, 1]), method = g[i, 2])

Cluster method   : single 
Distance         : euclidean 
Number of objects: 50
```

Comment: Interesting solution, this is what I was thinking of but could not get the way to get it working. expand.grid() is nice to know. The solution looks similar to James suggestion but somehow I feel more comfortable with that matrix alike structures. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `$` operator repeatedly, eg:

```
mname <-c("euclidean","maximum","manhattan")
lst <- sapply(mname,function(x) sapply(cname,function(y) hclust(dist(USArrests,x),y),simplify=F),simplify=F)
names(lst)<-rname
```

And you can use the following to reference,

```
lst$"u"$"ave"

Call:
hclust(d = dist(USArrests, x), method = y)

Cluster method   : average 
Distance         : euclidean 
Number of objects: 50
```

Unfortunately, `lst$rname[1]$cname[1]` doesn't work, but you can use `do.call`:

```
do.call(`$`,list(do.call(`$`,list(lst,rname[1])),cname[1]))

Call:
hclust(d = dist(USArrests, x), method = y)

Cluster method   : average 
Distance         : euclidean 
Number of objects: 50
```

**Edit**

There is actually a simpler version, but it will wear out your square bracket keys!

```
lst[[rname[1]]][cname[1]]
$ave

Call:
hclust(d = dist(USArrests, x), method = y)

Cluster method   : average 
Distance         : euclidean 
Number of objects: 50
```

**Edit 2**

The above square bracket notation seems to wrap the object in a `list` which means it doesn't return the object properly, but hadley's suggestion in the comments is clearer and avoids this problem:

```
lst[[c(rname[1],cname[1])]]
```

Comment: Use `lapply`, not `sapply(..., simplify = F)`.  You can also supply a vector to `[[`: `lst[[c("u","ave")]]`

Comment: @hadley I originally used `lapply`, but ended up using `sapply` because it sets names automatically, and with `simplify=F` is essentially the same as `lapply`. Good call with using a vector to `[[` it is much clearer to read and the method I posted wraps the item in a `list` so it doesn't return a `hclust` object.

Comment: Thanks. Exactly the solution I was looking for. Great help. Just need to play around to understand more the apply function family. never would have found the solution using lst[[c(rname[1],cname[1])]] by myself. That helped me a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Dataframes are quintessentially lists but with a "rectangular" format. Each entry within a list can contain a list. Thus, an idea you may wish to consider implementing would be "nested tables". A nested table contains a column housing the "main" distinguishing feature/category, and the second column contains the corresponding data. I provide a sample example showing the creation of a nested table, and some of the stuff you can use to manipulate/extract things.

```
    library(dplyr)
    library(tidyr)
    #mock_data creation
    samples <- c("Class A", "Class A", "Class B", "Class B")
    ht.in <- c(65, 66, 72, 75)
    wt.lb <- c(150, 160, 180, 210)
    BMI <- c(22, 24, 23, 26)
    data <- cbind.data.frame(samples, ht.in, wt.lb)
    View(data)
    #nesting data
    data_n <- data %>% group_by(samples) %>% nest() #%>% is a piping function. Takes the output from the left and pipes it into the function on the right. 
    #nested retrieval
    unnest(data_n)
    #Basic summary
    data_sum <- data %>% group_by(samples) %>% 
    summarise(mean.ht = mean(ht.in), 
      mean.lb = mean(wt.lb), mean.BMI = mean(BMI))
    #Combining summary with nested format 
    data_n_sum <- left_join(data_n, data_sum, by = "samples")
    #Extracting information via filtering and unnest()
    filter(data_n_sum, mean.ht < 70) %>%  #we filter our data_n_sum where the mean height is less than 70.
      select(samples, data) %>% #unnest only likes two columns, so we keep the two columns, one which has the nested info, and the other which contains the 'categorical' variable that belongs to the samples... 
        unnest()
    #Extracting information through $ and [[]]
    data_n_sum$data[[1]]$ht.in #You can loop through these numerical indices (lapply)
```

I like these quite a lot since they provide structure but enough flexibility to extract relevant data and whatnot. 
  Additional reading: https://blog.rstudio.com/2016/02/02/tidyr-0-4-0/